# Multi column list html

Tags: html, css

[image]

I would like to make the product list like above, i tried with the following code but its not looks good some one please suggest me in a right way,

```html
.tablep{
 float:left;
 padding-right:150px;
  }
 .bg{
  background-color:grey;
 }
```

```html
<div class="tablep bg">Code #</div><div class="tablep bg">Product Name</div><div class="tablep bg">Date</div><div class="tablep bg">Amount</div><br>
<div class="tablep">Id1</div><div class="tablep">product1</div><div class="tablep">2015</div><div class="tablep">100USD</div>
```

How can i achieve as like the pic.Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You should use a table for this kind of data. It's the semantically correct way.

A table matches it's size to all content. If you use divs like in your own code then they will not stretch nicely. I've created a table and gave it a width of 100%. That should give you exactly what you want.

The `tr` stands for table row, the `th` stands for table header and the `td` stands for table cell.

```css
.tablep {
    width: 100%;
}

.tablep th {
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablep" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Code #</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id1</td><td>product1</td><td>2015</td><td>100USD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id1</td><td>product1</td><td>2015</td><td>100USD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id1</td><td>product1</td><td>2015</td><td>100USD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can some changes in your css

```css
.tablep{
 float:left;
 width:20%;
  }
 .bg{
  background-color:grey;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="tablep bg">Code #</div><div class="tablep bg">Product Name</div><div class="tablep bg">Date</div><div class="tablep bg">Amount</div><br>
    <div class="tablep">Id1</div><div class="tablep">product1</div><div class="tablep">2015</div><div class="tablep">100USD</div>
```

Comment: Regarding the way he wants his data to be shown it would benifit him much more in the long run to use tables tho

Comment: @ThomasS I agree fully, I've posted an example using a table